# What's wrong with this Ruby code array1 << item if item = prepare_item

Tags: ruby

I wrote the following Ruby code

```
array1 << item if item = prepare_item
```

prepare_item is a method that either returns an object or nil array1 is an array of objects.

However the above code didn't work, I think some sort of exception was raised.

The following rewrite worked

```
if item = prepare_item
  array1 << item
end
```

So my question is: can you please explain how the above 2 snippets of code are different? What was wrong with the first snippet?

Comment: "I think some sort of exception was raised" doesn't really help us work out what your problem was. The exception and backtrace would give a lot of information about what the error was (that's why they give you that information)

Comment: thanks, but if i know what exception was raised, i wouldn't be asking this question.  but from a programming point of view, are the snippets above equivalent? and if no, how?

Comment: Well, I'd say that if one works, and the other doesn't, then, no, they're not equivalent... The first fails because you are trying to dereference `item` before you have defined it, which doesn't work in a conditional modifier context. The second works because `item` is defined as the return value of `prepare_item` before you dereference it with `Array#<<`

Answer (score -2):

you forgot one "=", so that the whole line should look like

```
array1 << item if item == prepare_item
```

Comment: thanks, but no, item = prepare_item is both assignment and testing if it's nil

Comment: Having a single equal sign instead of two is a common mistake, but it looks intentional here.